# (UE4) Simulate physics breaks timeline animation

Tags: physics-engine, unreal

I'm using timelines to animate my boat object, which does not have any limbs.  So all I need to accomplish is rotation and a little movement.

However, when the player dies, I need the boat to sink using simulate physics.
When I turn simulate physics on, the timelines stop animating the boat.

The nodes I'm using are GetActorTransform and SetActorRotation